# Google AdSense - providing access (via an additional account?) to a third party

Tags: google-adsense

I am working with a partner who will be handling the marketing side of things for one of my websites. He has informed me that he will require access to my AdSense account.

I need to create an additional account for him, so that he can access and manage Google AdWords/units etc, using his own login credentials. However, despite searching Google for a while now, I can't seem to locate any information that pertains to creating additional user accounts.

Does anyone know how I may do this?

Comment: Adwords and Adsense are two different services, which one does he need access to? I'm not sure there would be a valid reason to give access to Adsense, TBH.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat I double checked it is Adsense that he needs access to. The reason for that he is taken charge of all the advertising side of things and needs to set up channels etc. Also, he will need access to the data so that we can measure the effectiveness of layouts etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not only looking for AdSense, but if you are looking for general ad server solution, you should check out Doubleclick for Publishers:
http://www.google.com/intl/en/dfp/info/sb/index.html.

You can manage your inventory there, and if you have unsold inventory, you can also automatically add AdSense as a fallback there. You can also manage different users with different permissions there.

Comment: I am already, only using Google as a backup for serving ads. I am using another publishing network.

Comment: You can manage other networks through Doubleclick for Publishers as well. You can also set up different strategies based on the average eCPM that networks may give you.

Answer (score 0):

If it's AdWords, then there are only a couple of options that I can think of...

1. If your partner hasn't already signed up for a AdWords account, he can sign up for a My Client Center account (http://support.google.com/adwords/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1704399). This will give him full access to the AdWords account.
2. Try to find software that utilizes the AdWords API and of course, allow multiple logins

Answer (score 0):

The API for Adsense might work as well.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the API as well as to any documentation that might help?